# Redux React: Not able to access 'this' inside a function of another class

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a class named `iccSdk` which have a function with the name `on`. Now inside my React's `render`, i am calling the function `iccSdk.on()`. Further I want to dispatch an action from within this function so I try to use `this.props.actions.chatConnect(data);` but `this` is becoming undefined here.

1st attempt:

```
render() {
    console.log(this);
    iccSdk.on('connect', function(data) {
      console.log(this);
      this.props.actions.chatConnect(data);
    });
...
}
```

In above case `this` is shown as undefined inside the function but it looks good outside my iccSdk.on() function.

2nd attempt:

```
render() {
    var t = this;
    iccSdk.on('connect', function(data) {
      t.props.actions.chatConnect(data);
    });
...
}
```

In the 2nd attempt it works fine but I doubt is it a good practice to do so, and i am also confused why `this` is not accessible inside my iccSdk.on()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function creates a new scope. Therefore the context (=this) is different or does not exist. Your second approach is fine.

Other ways to do this:

**Arrow function:**

Arrow function does not create a new context for the function. Therefore you can use the same this inside your function. For this ES6 is required.

```
render() {
    console.log(this);
    iccSdk.on('connect', data => {
      console.log(this);
      this.props.actions.chatConnect(data);
    });
...
}
```

**Bind**

With bind function you can bind "this" to your function.

```
render() {
    console.log(this);
    iccSdk.on('connect', function(data) {
      console.log(this);
      this.props.actions.chatConnect(data);
    }.bind(this));
...
}
```

**thisArg**

iccSdk.on might also take "this argument". I'm not sure if it does. You can read more about thisArg here: https://h3manth.com/new/blog/2014/thisarg-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

`This` is a reference to an object which is given to a method. In a method you can access the given object and it is `This`. But `on` method is of `iccSdk`so, it can't access other objects by this variable. Every method can only access its own object.

So, if you want to access another object in a method, you can use your second attempt (it is normal I guess), or you can bind the method to the object you want to access like this:

```
function () {
    console.log(this)
}.bind(this)
```